# Can't Upgrade version Android Database sqlite using Dagger2

Tags: java, android, sqlite, dagger-2

I use the `dagger2` library for my application. then I use android `sqlite` for storing my data. the problem is that when I try to upgrade my database, my database version doesn't change. is there something wrong with my logic?

this is my `AppModule` class :

```
public class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Context provideContext(Application application) {
        return application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    ApiHelper provideApiHelper(AppApiHelper appApiHelper) {
        return appApiHelper;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    DataManager provideDataManager(AppDataManager appDataManager) {
        return appDataManager;
    }

    @Provides
    @DatabaseInfo
    String provideDatabaseName() {
        return AppConstants.DB_NAME;
    }

    @Provides
    @DatabaseInfo
    Integer provideDatabaseVersion(PreferencesHelper preferencesHelper) {
        return preferencesHelper.getVersion();
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Gson provideGson() {
        return new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
    }

    @Provides
    @PreferenceInfo
    String providePreferenceName() {
        return AppConstants.PREF_NAME;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    PreferencesHelper providePreferencesHelper(AppPreferencesHelper appPreferencesHelper) {
        return appPreferencesHelper;
    }

    @Provides
    SchedulerProvider provideSchedulerProvider() {
        return new AppSchedulerProvider();
    }
}
```

this is my `Datamanager` class :

```
public class AppDataManager implements DataManager {

private final ApiHelper mApiHelper;

private final Context mContext;

private final Gson mGson;

private final PreferencesHelper mPreferencesHelper;

private DatabaseSqlite  mDatabaseSqlite;
private Insert mInsert;
private Select mSelect;

@Inject
public AppDataManager(Context context, PreferencesHelper preferencesHelper, ApiHelper apiHelper, Gson gson, DatabaseSqlite databaseSqlite,
                      Insert insert, Select select) {
    mContext = context;
    mPreferencesHelper = preferencesHelper;
    mGson = gson;
    mApiHelper = apiHelper;
    mDatabaseSqlite = databaseSqlite;
    mInsert = insert;
    mSelect = select;

}

@Override
public DatabaseSqlite setDatabaseSqlite(Context context, int Version, ArrayList<Lst_App_version_Log> app_version_log) {
    mDatabaseSqlite = new DatabaseSqlite(context, Version, app_version_log);
    return mDatabaseSqlite;
} // I try to pass data into costructor my Database Sqlite

}
```

and this is my `DatabaseSqlite` class :

```
public class DatabaseSqlite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String TAG = "DatabaseSqlite";
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Log_version> mlogVersion = null;

@Inject
public DatabaseSqlite(Context context,
                      @DatabaseInfo String dbName,
                      @DatabaseInfo Integer version) {
    super(context, dbName, null, version);
}

public DatabaseSqlite(Context context, int version, ArrayList<Log_version> version_log) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, version);
    this.mlog_version = version_log;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    if (app_version_log != null) {
        for (Log_version dataUpdateModel : Log_version) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: " + dataUpdateModel.getId());
                db.execSQL(dataUpdateModel.getQuer());
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: Finish");

    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < newVersion) {
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

and this is how the way I try to update my database version :

```
 getDataManager().setVersion(itemVersionResponse.getVersion());
        getDataManager().setDatabaseSqlite(context, itemVersionResponse.getVersion(), dataUpdateModels);
```

Is there something wrong that makes my database version is not upgrade? please I hope somebody can tell me where is my false. thank you very much

Comment: Show the Dagger2 Modules and Components in which you Provide the `@DatabaseInfo version`

Comment: I already put modules at there